# Perl adding corresponding/respective values of array to variables

Tags: arrays, perl

I have some scalar values in array

```
@array=(1,2,3,4,5);
```

We can directly assign these values to variables as

```
($a,$b,$c,$d,$e)=@array;
```

Is there some way so that I can add the corresponding values of @array numbers like
$x +=10;

```
($a,$b,$c,$d,$e) +=@array;
```

Sorry for asking such silly question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum all elements of array using `sum` from `List::Util`:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);

my $sum = sum(@array);
```

---

**UPDATE**:
It seems that you want to add arrays element by element, then you can use `pairwise` from `List::Moreutils`:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(pairwise);

my @array = qw(10 20 30);
my @incr  = qw( 1  2  3);
pairwise { $a += $b } @array, @incr;   # (11,22,33)
```

Comment: I don't want sum of all elements in array instead I need the values of the variables $a,$b,$c.. to be increased by corresponding values in array

Comment: or just `my $i = 0; map {$_+=$array[$i]; $i++;} ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);`

Comment: @Suic thanks n +1 that is the solution that i am using...as I don't have to reassign the values to the variable

Answer (score 1):

Try using `map`

```
my @array=(1,2,3,4,5);
my ($a,$b,$c,$d,$e) = map { $_ + 10 } @array;
```